# Is there a way to upgrade Vivo V5 from Marshmallow to Pie?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 9.0-pie, vivo

I am having an Android device Vivo V5, Which has Android Marshmallow installed. Now, I want to upgrade the OS to Android Pie.
Please suggest me any workaround.

Comment: Please let me know why the question gets a downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but assuming the device is not officially supported anymore, the only way is to find Android Pie-based custom ROM that supports your device (if exists). I only found [mostly Android Nougat on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/vivo-5/development).